# Redmine: adding more "edit" buttons for specific actions

Tags: redmine

In Redmine, I can use edit button to edit everything of an issue. However, in daily work, the most frequent actions other than update the issue status are "resolve an issue", "close an issue" and sometimes, "re-activate an issue". When resolving an issue, the "assign to" field will be updated to the opener and issue status to "resolved".

I used to add an js to the issue details page to do similar work but it will be gone after redmine upgrading. What's the correct way to do accomplish this task?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your custom code to be preserved while doing Redmine upgrades, there are few options:

1. make it a plugin
2. install Redmine via svn or git, and perform code updates, it should preserve code that you wrote, and automatically merge rest of
   the code
3. run your custom javascript via greasemonkey or tampermonkey